# CREATE TABLE, ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error

Tags: sql, oracle

This error pops up when trying to execute script shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE "ATTRACTION_MH"(
"AttractionNo" NUMBER(11) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"CityName" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ENABLE,
"AttractionName" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"Category" VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"AllocatedTime" NUMBER(3) NOTNULL ENABLE
```

Only table shown below is created:

```
CREATE TABLE "CITY_MH"(
"CityName" VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ENABLE,
"TourID" NUMBER(11,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"HotelName" VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"NumberOfNights" NUMBER(11,0) NOT NULL ENABLE)
```

For this table pops up this same error:

```
CREATE TABLE "TOUR_MH" (
"TourID" NUMBER(11,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ENABLE,
"TourTitle" VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"Cost" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 2000 ENABLE)

ALTER TABLE "CITY_MH"
FOREIGN KEY ("TourID") REFERENCES "Tour_MH" ("TourID") ENABLE;

ALTER TABLE "ATTRACTION_MH"
ADD UNIQUE ("AttractionName") ENABLE;
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the missing right parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're literally missing a )

```
CREATE TABLE ATTRACTION_MH(
AttractionNo NUMBER(11) NOT NULL ENABLE,
CityName VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ENABLE,
AttractionName VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL ENABLE,
Category VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ENABLE,
AllocatedTime NUMBER(3) NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

Also, don't quote the object names, mixed/case sensitive object names in oracle are a pain for everyone involved, and you'll have to live with that...forever.

For your 2nd table, the DEFAULT value comes before the inline NOT NULL constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE TOUR_MH (
TourID NUMBER(11,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ENABLE,
TourTitle VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL ENABLE,
Cost NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 2000 NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

Your ALTER TABLE is wrong. To add a foreign key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
    ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name FOREIGN KEY ( local_col)
        REFERENCES other_table( other_table_col )
    NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

Your 2nd one is wrong too.

```
alter table table_name add constraint constraint_name unique(column_name);
```

Feel free to use our free design and database GUI tools, [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/sqldeveloper).  They can help you draw/design/build your objects...and learn the syntax!

Comment: Thanks! Can you also check ALTER TABLE? It seems that something is wrong there

Comment: @Matt Done. Now me a favor, next time you need help, consult the docs and try our database tools.

Comment: I will! Thanks!